# Quick easy way to turn all std output into logging within Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm adjusted my logging levels to warn `log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console` but is essentially the same as the `.template`  , but is there a way I can not suppress all output but instead pipe it all into logs. Are there any logs created - I certainly cannot find them in `var/log`

Comment: by default logs goes to the work directory of the worker nodes. work/appname/executorid/stdout or stderr

Comment: I'm running as standalone.